# Wordpress premium theme development

Tags: plugins, theme-development

How to include all plugin files with the wordpress theme so that when i distribute the theme , the theme must ask the user to install recommended plugins. how do we achieve that??! for example. i am lets assume i am using WP Bakery Page builder ive paid for it and have got the license,, i build a theme using wp bakery page builder when the user downloads it and installs the theme, theme must ask him to install recommended plugin(i.e WP Bakery Page builder) and when he installs the plugin,, plugin shouldnt ask him to get license or get premium key?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

It’s a PHP library that allows you to define which plugins are required and which are recommended. You can use plugins from WP repository, from given link or bundle plugin with your theme...